# Offsite nagios?

Tags: monitoring, nagios

Nagios is great for self-hosted service monitoring in an intranet, but what about offsite monitoring? Does anyone sell a network service availability service that goes beyond ping and HTTP?

Comment: As suggested in the comments, you can build your own solution with tools like nagios/phantomjs or you can rent the service from companies like witbe or iplabel. I think this question should be asked once again now in 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plenty of places will do off-site monitoring.  Typically you will see [Solarwinds Orion](http://www.solarwinds.com), [NetQoS Netvoyant](http://www.netqos.com), and [Zenoss](http://www.zenoss.com/) offered before Nagios though(at least from what I've seen offered).

Answer (score 3):

I just rent a VPS for ~$30/month and run nagios on it as well.  Seems to work great.

Answer (score 0):

I use a combination of munin + nagios :

munin on all my offsite nodes, [check_munin_rrd.pl](http://github.com/jrottenberg/Nagios-Munin/tree/master) on nagios (granted nagios host can read the generated rrd files)

check_munin_rrd.pl reads the rrd munin generates and alert you if anything goes above a threshold, so you can monitor anything that munin can see (cpu, load, network)
It's not real time (data gathering every 5 min). For real time, you could also have a look on a regular snmp solution but it's a bit tricky in my opinion. In a sense munin-node becomes your snmp agent.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I would look at using nagios on an offsite host (like http://www.slicehost.com/).  Install it there securely, then allow for a tunneled ssl link back into your main nagios system.  Then you can have a single place to monitor all of your systems internal and external.

Answer (score 0):

I saw people renting an amazon cloud host to have a nagios running there... I think it is a nice solution :).

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone sell a network service availability service that goes beyond ping and HTTP?

yes, of course; we do :)

nagios has the ability for long, to have local checks executed via NRPE (nagios remote plugin executor) which can be seen as an agent on the remote machine that executes requested plugins locally and delivers results and perfdata back to the nagios_server.

that way you're able to check local parameters from remote. check [this plugin](https://bitbucket.org/maresystem/dogtown-nagios-plugins/src/de0c8aac970471b17ce9e1e1eec0c31f3ca457c6/check_psinfo?at=master) to see which information might be collected from os/process-table.

btw, there is an nrpe-connector for windows too which works like charme.